# Python Auto fill a column based on another column

Tags: python-3.x

Dataframe is as below:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Stat': ['Good', 'Bad', 'Good', 'Good'], 'Prod': ['A', 'A', 'B', 'C']})
```

I want to have a result that for the same Prod, if one of the entry have Status = "Bad", then a new column will have Remark as "Redo". The final outcome should be:

```
Stat   Prod   Remark
Good     A     Redo
Bad      A     Redo
Good     B     OK
Good     C     OK
```

I know I can perhaps try to use groupby on Prod. But then to read "Stat" from the groupby seems challenging. I have tried if IF statement after groupby but not working...

Any idea?

Comment: Please can you clarify your question as with your current specification is seems as if the first row should show 'OK'. What is the exact specification you need for the Remark column to show 'Redo'?

Comment: For the same Prod, if one of the entry have Status = "Bad", then a new column will have Remark as "Redo"